# How to make a shadow look in bottom of a listview or girdview cell like flipboard in android

Tags: android, listview, blur, shadow, flipboard

am new to android i need to display some data which i have done, but what i need is the look of each cells in the list-view. my requirement is that to add a light shadow in the bottom of each cell in the list view which is similar as the cells in the flip board .
The image looks like in the url [Image Required](http://postimg.org/image/xyi4gq0x7/)
(i dont have enough rep to post an image so please check the image in the given lik)

see the black circle,exactly a shadow look in each cell, i have goggled and had some research  in github repo but i get result like adding blur or something ,but its not gives this effect, i have tryed  [BlurTestAndroid](https://github.com/patrickfav/BlurTestAndroid)

and other blur effects but its not giving the result i need. can  anyone help me to achieve this effect or any ideas to make my listview cell like this, is blurring is the right way to achieve this or have any other solution to do this.

Thank you

Comment: That image link is not clear. Add some other clear sample url

Comment: its a shadow effect like the flipboard app